# When opening files in unix, what does "!$" syntax mean?

Tags: unix

Here's the sample code:

```
user$ touch file.txt
user$ mate !$
```

"mate" is calling textmate text editor, and that second command opens the previously created file.txt.  what is this !$ syntax?  what does ! do? what does $ do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shell feature called in various shells history expansion or history substitution.

Words starting with an exclamation mark are replaced with words from previously executed commands. Which words and which commands, it depends on the rest of the word.

In this particular example the dollar sign refers to the last word of a command, and since there is no other character between '!' and '$' the referenced command is the previous one, so !$ gets replaced with the last argument of the prevoius command.

What other command and word specifiers exist differ somewhat between shells.

Answer (score 2):

`!$`, in the Bash shell, refers to the last word in the previous command, here `file.txt`.

The `$`, borrowing from regular expression and `ed`/`vi` command syntax, means "last".

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it in the documentation for your shell.

Unfortunately, shell documentation typically doesn't show the `!` and `$` characters together, which makes searching for `!$` unnecessarily difficult.  (The `!` introduces a history substitution; the `$` modifies it, making it refer to just the last word.)

For tcsh, `man tcsh` or visit [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) and search for "History substitution".

For bash, `man bash` and search for "HISTORY EXPANSION", or `info bash` or visit the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), specifically the sections on [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) and [event designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators).